# jQuery treetable alignment issue when text wraps to next line

Tags: jquery, treetable

Using the jQuery tree-table plug-in and struggling to get the CSS to properly align text when the branch name or leaf name wraps to the next line, see picture. *Note that the link names are the node names; my real world table column width is much smaller than the JSFiddle so wrapping is a real issue*.
[image]

HTML is generated from server; I have some flexibility here

[See JSFiddle that mimics the generated HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/cropredy/yLb25dy9/173/) and includes the plugin's CSS plus default theme.

I tried ([inspired by](http://jsfiddle.net/vandigroup/upKGe/132/))

```
table.treetable a.node {
  overflow: hidden;
}

table.treetable span.indenter {
  float: left;
}
```

but this yields:
[image]

Similar issue [raised here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860960/jquery-treetable-text-aligned-to-icon-span-indenter) but the provided answer doesn't seem to actually work in the answer's JSFiddle.

Lengthy discussion on [jquery-treetable gitHub closed issue #142](https://github.com/ludo/jquery-treetable/issues/142) so I ...
tried :

```
table.treetable span.indenter {
  float:left;
}
table.treetable a.node {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

(this handles the parent node wrap OK but mis-justifies its child leaf as well as the standalone leaf Node 2)

Lastly tried the "solution" the #142's OP said worked

```
table.treetable span.indent{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  }
```

This had no effect.  I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is what you're after
[image]

Then a simple solution may be to set absolute position to "indenter" to the left of the cell and then shift text using padding ...

```
table.treetable tbody tr td { position: relative; padding-left: 25px; }
table.treetable tbody tr td span.indenter { position: absolute; left: 5px; }
```